# (R) making function to change moth_code to english sentence goes wrong

Tags: r, function, for-loop, indexing, morse-code

I'm changing morse code into english sentence using functions but it doesn't work well.

This is the basic data frame for morse code and english

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
       "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
       "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "", " ")
b <- c("dD", "Dddd", "DdDd", "Ddd", "d", "ddDd", "DDd", "dddd", "dd", "dDDD",
       "DdD", "dDdd", "DD", "Dd", "DDD", "dDDd", "DDdD", "dDd", "ddd", "D",
       "ddD", "dddD", "dDD", "DddD", "DdDD", "DDdd", "s",  "ss")

moth <- data.frame(a,b)
names(moth)=c("Alphabet", "moth_code")
```

And this is the sentence I want to interpret.

```
d<- ("DdDDsDDDsddDssdDDsddsdDddsdDddssddDdsdDsDdDdsdssDDsdDsDdsDdDDssDddsdsddDdsdsdDsDsdddssddsDdssdDddsddsddDdsdssDdddsddDsDssDdsdsdddDsdsdDdssdDddsdsDssDdDDsDDDsddDsdDdsdddsdsdDddsddDdssDdddsdssDddsdsddDdsdsdDsDsdsDdd")
f <- c()      
g <- c()
```

This is the function I made.

```
moth_Alphabet <- function(x){
  x <- strsplit(x, split='s')
  x <- unlist(x)
  for(i in 1:69){
    f[i]<-match(d[i], moth$moth_code)  
    g[i]<-moth$Alphabet[f[i]]   
    if(is.na(g[i])==TRUE){
      g[i]<-" "
    }
  }
  h <- paste(g, collapse="") 
  l <- sub('y', 'Y', h) 
  l
}

moth_Alphabet(d)
```

moth_Alphabet(d) should be
"You will face many defeats in life but never let yourself be defeated"

but it didn't work.

This is what I tried.

```
d <- strsplit(d, split='s')
d <- unlist(d)
d

moth_Alphabet <- function(x){
  x <- strsplit(x, split='s')
  x <- unlist(x)
  for(i in 1:69){
    f[i]<-match(d[i], moth$moth_code) 
    g[i]<-moth$Alphabet[f[i]]  
    if(is.na(g[i])==TRUE){
      g[i]<-" "
    }
  }
  h <- paste(g, collapse="") 
  l <- sub('y', 'Y', h) 
  l
}
moth_Alphabet(d)
```

```
d <- strsplit(d, split='s')
d <- unlist(d)
d
```

after coding this before the 'moth_Alphabet' function, the code worked well but 'moth_Alphabet' code itself without the upper code doesn't work well. I need your help. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d[i]` inside the function doesn't work as `d` is a single string.

```
moth_Alphabet <- function(x){
     f <- c()      
     g <- c()
  x <- strsplit(x, split='s')
  x <- unlist(x)
 for(i in seq_along(x)){
     tmp <-match(x[i], moth$moth_code)
     f <- c(f, tmp)
     tmp2 <- moth$Alphabet[tmp]   
     if(is.na(tmp2)){
           tmp2<-" "
         }
     g <- c(g, tmp2)
  
  }
  h <- paste(g, collapse="") 
    l <- sub('y', 'Y', h) 
    l
  
  }
```

-testing

```
> d<- "DdDDsDDDsddDssdDDsddsdDddsdDddssddDdsdDsDdDdsdssDDsdDsDdsDdDDssDddsdsddDdsdsdDsDsdddssddsDdssdDddsddsddDdsdssDdddsddDsDssDdsdsdddDsdsdDdssdDddsdsDssDdDDsDDDsddDsdDdsdddsdsdDddsddDdssDdddsdssDddsdsddDdsdsdDsDsdsDdd"
> moth_Alphabet(d)
[1] "You will face many defeats in life but never let yourself be defeated"
```